Working with variables in custom commands in vifm (file manager)
In vifm help I found how to declare and use variables (options)
:let &[l:|g:]opt = <expr>
    sets option value.
...
option                                         *vifm-expr-option*
------
&option               option value (local one is preferred, if exists)
...
Examples: >
echo 'Terminal size: '.&columns.'x'.&lines
if &columns > 100

and have written a simple command in vifmrc
command! ttest : let &l:name = '%a'
        \| if &name != ''
        \|   echo &name
        \| endif

but it fails with error :endif without :if
I've tried to use name and &l:name with the same result.
If I use enviroment variable $name instead of a local option it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?


use variables (options)

Options aren't variables.  Options are things that can be set via :set command.  The only kind of writable variables supported by :let is environment variables.

but it fails with error :endif without :if

What happens in this case is that a more recent error hides the previous ones.  If you use :messages, you'll see all of them:
Unknown local option name: name
Invalid expression: &name != ''
Invalid expression: &name
:endif without :if

:endif without :if is a result of :if command failing due to unknown option name.

Thanks for the help.
But now I don't understand what is this part of vifm help about. Do you have and idea?
It defenitily mention let with an option.
:let &[l:|g:]opt = <expr>
    sets option value.

And in general, what should be used in commands defintion, options or environment variables? For me, envvar is a quite general thing to use it as a varible in command.

:let can be used either to set environment variables or as an alternative syntax for :set.

When it comes to environment variables think of how they are used in shells.  As to what should you use (option/envvar) depends entirely on what you're trying to do in a particular command.
